# Unable to resolve "./LogBoxImages/close.png"

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I wanted to add scss transformer to it. But I am getting this eroor that I can not find the solution anywhere.

My customFormater.js file:

```
// For React Native version 0.59 or later
var upstreamTransformer = require("metro-react-native-babel-transformer");
var sassTransformer = require("react-native-sass-transformer");
var svgTransformer = require("react-native-svg-transformer");

module.exports.transform = function({ src, filename, options }) {
  if (filename.endsWith(".scss") || filename.endsWith(".sass")) {
    return sassTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  } else if (filename.endsWith(".svg")) {
    return svgTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  }  else {
    return upstreamTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  }
};
```

My metro.config.js file

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("./customTransformer.js")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg" && ext!=="scss"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg", "scss", "sass"]
    }
  };
})();
```

It works on web perfect but when I try to open it with expo on ios I am getting this error:

```
iOS Bundling failed 262ms (C:\Users\siar\Desktop\reactNativeApps\button-app\index.js)
Unable to resolve "./LogBoxImages/close.png" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\UI\LogBoxNotification.js"
```

Comment: It might help to clear the cache as described here ```https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/clear-cache-windows/#expo-cli-and-npm```